# Updating to MySQLi and having some trouble

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I've spent a bit of time looking at MySQLi and I'm having trouble updating a script with the new functions. This script is used for a dynamic dropdown form, using data sent to it using JS. You can find a live version of the script **[here](http://new.foxmeter.com/find.php)** to check out what I'm takling about. I've looked up and down my code and have compared it to other MySQLi examples and I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong.

Now, the first dropdown doesn't even initiate a query, all the PHP does is return predefined results as it's just simpler for the first option. What's weird, to me, is that even the first drop down is now not working when it does not rely at all on the MySQLi connection. It all worked before updating, just for reference.

Here's my script:

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbDatabase);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

//prevents injections
//any order
isset($_GET['type'])?$type = urldecode($_GET['type']):"";
isset($_GET['source'])?$source = $db->real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['source'])):"";
isset($_GET['range'])?$power = $db->real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['range'])):"";
isset($_GET['setpoint'])?$setpoint = $db->real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['setpoint'])):"";

//forms the query depending on what data is recieved through GET
//first option on the bottom; last option on the top to avoid conflicts 
if (isset($_GET['setpoint'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT stp FROM meters WHERE sio='$range' AND pso='$power' AND stp='$setpoint' ORDER BY model";
} elseif (isset($_GET['power'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT stp FROM meters WHERE sio='$range' AND pso='$power' ORDER BY model";
} elseif (isset($_GET['range'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT pso FROM meters WHERE sio='$range' ORDER BY model";
} elseif (isset($_GET['source'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT sir FROM meters WHERE sio LIKE '%$source%' ORDER BY sir";
}

//creates a result array from query results
isset($query)?$result = $db->query($query):"";

//outputs dropdown options dependent on what GET variables are set
//first option on the bottom; last option on the top to avoid conflicts
if (isset($_GET['setpoint'])) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['stp'] . "'>" . $row['stp'] . "</option>";
    $result->free();
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['power'])) {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Setpoint Options</option>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row{'stp'} = ucfirst($row{'stp'}); //capitalizes the first letter; necessary?
        echo "<option value='" . $row['stp'] . "'>" . $row['stp'] . "</option>";
    $result->free();
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['source'])) {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Range</option>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['sir'] . "'>" . $row['sir'] . "</option>";
    $result->free();
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "Digital") {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Source</option>";
    echo "<option value='RS232C'>RS232C</option><option value='RS422'>RS422</option><option value='RS485'>RS485</option><option value='current loop'>current loop</option>";
    $result->free();
} elseif (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "Analog") {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Source</option>";
    echo "<option value='DC current'>DC Current</option><option value='DC voltage'>DC Voltage</option><option value='AC current'>AC Current</option><option value='AC voltage'>AC Voltage</option><option value='process'>Process</option><option value='thermocouple'>Thermocouple</option><option value='RDT'>rdt</option>";
    $result->free();
}
```

edit: This is my old code using the deprecated method.

```
$con = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL Server. Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbDatabase) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to database {$dbDatabase}. Error: " . mysql_error());


//prevents injections
//any order
isset($_GET['type'])?$type = urldecode($_GET['type']):"";
//$type = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['type']));
isset($_GET['source'])?$source = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['source'])):"";
isset($_GET['range'])?$power = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['range'])):"";
isset($_GET['setpoint'])?$setpoint = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET['setpoint'])):"";

//forms the query depending on what data is recieved through GET
//first option on the bottom; last option on the top to avoid conflicts 
if (isset($_GET['setpoint'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT stp FROM meters WHERE sio='$range' AND pso='$power' AND stp='$setpoint' ORDER BY model";
} elseif (isset($_GET['power'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT stp FROM meters WHERE sio='$range' AND pso='$power' ORDER BY model";
} elseif (isset($_GET['range'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT pso FROM meters WHERE sio='$range' ORDER BY model";
} elseif (isset($_GET['source'])) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT sir FROM meters WHERE sio LIKE '%$source%' ORDER BY sir";
}

//creates a result array from query results
isset($query)?$result = mysql_query($query):"";

//outputs dropdown options dependent on what GET variables are set
//first option on the bottom; last option on the top to avoid conflicts
if (isset($_GET['setpoint'])) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row{'stp'} . "'>" . $row{'stp'} . "</option>";
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['power'])) {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Setpoint Options</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row{'stp'} = ucfirst($row{'stp'}); //capitalizes the first letter; necessary?
        echo "<option value='" . $row{'stp'} . "'>" . $row{'stp'} . "</option>";
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['source'])) {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Range</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row{'sir'} . "'>" . $row{'sir'} . "</option>";
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "Digital") {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Source</option>";
    echo "<option value='RS232C'>RS232C</option><option value='RS422'>RS422</option><option value='RS485'>RS485</option><option value='current loop'>current loop</option>";
} elseif (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "Analog") {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Source</option>";
    echo "<option value='DC current'>DC Current</option><option value='DC voltage'>DC Voltage</option><option value='AC current'>AC Current</option><option value='AC voltage'>AC Voltage</option><option value='process'>Process</option><option value='thermocouple'>Thermocouple</option><option value='RDT'>rdt</option>";
}
```

Comment: You should check for errors with your query. `if(!result) echo $mysqli->error;`

Comment: Can you add `echo $result->num_rows();` after you run the query. I'm curious if it how many results it gets. Also, posting the old code *might* be helpful.

Comment: Hey sorry I went on lunch soon after posting and forgot to respond. I'll try it out right now and I'll add my working code at the bottom of the post.

Comment: My problem right now though is that it doesn't make it to the query yet. My first dropdown doesn't create a query being how few options and results there are. I just hand wrote options (last two elseifs). $result doesn't even get set yet because of this! Hm..

Comment: so `$range` is never defined. So it looks like the only query that works would be the `$_GET['source']` query

Comment: Oh that's weird! I actually fixed that earlier but must have `Ctrl+Z`ed at one point and changed it back. That doesn't affect my first textbox, though, which so far is the biggest problem I'm having.

Comment: Also, I should have removed them since they're currently not used but the first power and setpoint query can be overlooked because I'm still changing around the questions it asks. Once the first few textboxes work it's pretty modular and adding/removing questions is pretty easy.

Comment: Unless you have to use MySQLi, it might be easier to go straight to PDO. Prepared statements are a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing your `$result` inside the while loop. This will cause the loop to fail on the second iteration.

Since you are freeing the result in all of the ifs, why don't you just do it once at the end?

```
...
} elseif (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "Analog") {
    echo "<option>Please Choose Input Source</option>";
    echo "<option value='DC current'>DC Current</option><option value='DC voltage'>DC Voltage</option><option value='AC current'>AC Current</option><option value='AC voltage'>AC Voltage</option><option value='process'>Process</option><option value='thermocouple'>Thermocouple</option><option value='RDT'>rdt</option>";
}

$result->free();
```

However this doesn't explain why analog and digital won't work still..

Comment: Thanks for the `$result->free()` advice. Still can't figure out where it's failing itself, though. From the working script to this I have only changed the MySQL functions to MySQLi.